# Is this proof of $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I want to show that $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$.
Is this proof correct?

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $\delta = \epsilon$. For $0 < |x-2| < \delta$, we have

$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2}| = |\frac{2-x}{2x}|< \frac{|x-2|}{|x|} < |x-2| < \delta = \epsilon$

QED.

Comment: you need to pick $\delta$ more carefully if you want $\frac{1}{|x|}<1$

Comment: how about $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+1}$?

Answer (score 2):

For the following inequality
$$
\frac{|x-2|}{|x|}<|x-2|
$$
to hold, you need 
$$
|x|>1
$$
$\delta<1$. I would reccomend taking $\delta=\min\{ \epsilon,1\}$ to rectify this.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.
You used $1/|x|<1$, but it does not follow from your assumptions.

You need some bound on $1/x$.
To do so, you can for example choose $\delta<1$, so that $x>1$.
That is, you need to make $\delta$ small enough to avoid the trouble near $x=0$.
Can you finish the proof with this modification?

Answer (score 0):

No, as explained by others.  (Try $\varepsilon = \delta = 1.9$, $x = 0.1$.)  You know what the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is around $x = 2$, so you should know the ratio of $\delta$ to $\varepsilon$ in a neighborhood of $x = 2$.